# Axios response interceptor always returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

apiCaller an Axios instance which uses the function `processResponse` for processing the response. It sends the coresponding object to the frontend.

But when I try to access the response in the frontend, it always shows that response is `undefined`. The response gets printed correctly in the `processResponse` function but it can't be accessed from the frontend API call.

The `processResponse` function is :

```
const processResponse=(res) => {
    console.log(res.status);
    if (res.status===200) {
        return {isSuccess: true, data: res.data};
    }
    else {
        return {
            isFailure: true,
            status: res?.status,
            msg: res?.msg,
            code: res?.code
        };
    }
};
```

The Axios response interceptor is:

```
apiCaller.interceptors.response.use(
    function (res) {
        return processResponse(res);
    },
    function (err) {
        return Promise.reject(processError(err));
    }
);
```

It returns the rejected Promise properly but not the response.

the call from the frontend:

```
const signupUser=async () => {
        const tmp={
            username: username,
            name: name,
            password: password,
        };
        let res=await API.usersignup(tmp);
        console.log(res);
        if (res.isSuccess) {
            setName("");
            setUsername("");
            setPassword("");
            changeLogin;
        }
        else {
            setErr("Oops! Something went wrong :(");
        }
    };
```

This is where it always shows res is `undefined`.

Comment: Please provide the code related to API.usersignup. The processing above seems fine, but it's possible that when calling it, the promise from axios is not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to create the API using the Axios instance is incorrect.
I also faced the same issue and determined that the root cause is the use of brackets. This is my incorrect code:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(SERVICE_URLS)) {
  API[key] = (body, showUploadProgress, showDownloadProgress) => {
    axiosInstance({
      method: value.method,
      url: value.url,
      data: body,
      responseType: value.responseType,
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showUploadProgress) {
          let percentageCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
          showUploadProgress(percentageCompleted)
        }
      }, onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showUploadProgress) {
          let percentageCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
          showDownloadProgress(percentageCompleted)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Correct code is this:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(SERVICE_URLS)) {
  API[key] = (body, showUploadProgress, showDownloadProgress) => 
    axiosInstance({
      method: value.method,
      url: value.url,
      data:body,
      responseType: value.responseType,
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showUploadProgress) {
          let percentageCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
          showUploadProgress(percentageCompleted)
        }
      }, onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showUploadProgress) {
          let percentageCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
          showDownloadProgress(percentageCompleted)
        }
      }
    })
}
```

See at line 2 I'm using an arrow function, where before it was not an arrow function.